# issues using e.target.tagName or .prop in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have following logic that works great in all browsers I tested, besides ie8

```
$('.has_tags li').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('tag_clicked') && e.target.tagName !== 'LABEL') {
            $(this)
                .removeClass('tag_clicked')
                .children('input').prop('checked', false);

    } else if (!$(this).hasClass('tag_clicked') && e.target.tagName !== 'LABEL') {
            $(this)
                .addClass('tag_clicked')
                .children('input').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

In a nutshell it checks if a list element is clicked, if it iss ads class to it that styles current list and checks associated input, however if label inside such list element is clicked, than it ignores it as click on label is equal to click on checkbox. However, ie8 handles it well when list element is clicked, but when label associated to it is clicked nothing happens. Here is [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/aL5uuwng/)

Answer (score 1):

I propose to add event on INPUT and triggers it when you click on LI

```
$('.has_tags li').on('click', function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);
    var $input = $(this).find('input');

    if($target.closest('input').length || $target.closest('label').length) return;

    $input.prop('checked', !$input.prop('checked')).trigger('change');
});

$('.has_tags input').on('change.checkbox', function(e){
    var $input = $(this).closest('li');

    if(this.checked) {
        $input.addClass('tag_clicked');
    } else {
        $input.removeClass('tag_clicked');
    }
}).trigger('change.checkbox');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aL5uuwng/1/

Comment: And... You can delete LI event if you change your HTML&CSS

Comment: Has this worked for you on ie8, I see what you suggest and have implemented it, however still no luck in ie8